# pdf paragraph or blocks of text positions

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to retrieve the rectangles that make up paragraphs and/or blocks of text in a PDF page.

I have looked at iTextSharp and DataLogics.

The best I have been able to do is find an individual words.  However, I need to know if the words are in the same block of text.

I am using C#.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

UNless its structured PDF, this is not going to exist. The PDF is a set of drawString commands at locations - there are no paragraph or space markers. You need to work this out from the text positions.

Answer (score 1):

Extract all the coordinates of each word on the page, then try to group them together.

The first thing to do is to group into lines. To do this you want to loop through all words with all order words and group together the ones where the y0 is less than the y1 of the other, while the y1 is greater than the y0 of the other. These are lines.

Then you need to group your lines into paragraphs. The x position of the beginning of the line should be within 1/25th of the page width of the other. And the distance between the y coordinates of the line should be less than the height of the line. These are paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

This is in Java, but it deals with getting the content from the pdf then getting the value from the index within the content.

I am not sure, but you might be able to achieve something similar in C#.  Get the content and print it out.

```
//create a new reader from the source file
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
//create the file array
RandomAccessFileOrArray raf = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fileName);
//get the content of the pdf reader (which is the source file)
byte bContent [] = reader.getPageContent(1,raf);
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bs.write(bContent);
//create a string of the contents of the page in order to get the data needed
String contentOf1099 = bs.toString();
if(debug)
{
    System.err.println("contentOf1099 = "+contentOf1099);
}
//get the value based off an index
String value = contentOf1099.substring(contentOf1099.indexOf((",contentOf1099.indexOf("155 664 Td"))+1,contentOf1099.indexOf("(",contentOf1099.indexOf("155 664 Td "))+12);
```

Comment: birdlips, that last line is really giving me trouble.  can you break that down for me?

Comment: for sure, basically what I am doing there is saying "get me the next 12 characters at the index of 155 664 Td".  Everything on the PDF has a "location" with a defined address of sorts.  If you print out the content of the pdf, you might be able to determine what lies within the rectangle.